# Only print the rows that have at least one column that is NULL?

Tags: sql, oracle

so I am working on an SQL Oracle query, that is supposed to look through a database and print a new table that shows ONLY those rows which have at least one Column thats NULL.
This is the code I have at the moment :

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT AD.DE, AD.AT, AD.LO
       FROM  M.AD AD
     )SourceTable      
PIVOT (
    MAX(DE)
    FOR (LO)    
    IN(0 0, 1 1, 2 2)
)PivotTable
```

Does anyone know How I can make this work?

I tried to add a Where clause to the end that checks if ether 0,1 or 2 are NULL but I will get back  no results at all.

Comment: Hi - your question says you need to look through a database but your SQL is querying a single table. Can you clarify the requirement: do you need to search a single table or do you need to loop through all tables in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the identifiers for the pivot columns and then use a `WHERE` filter:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  ( SELECT DE, AT, LO
        FROM   M.AD
      )
      PIVOT (
        MAX(DE) AS DE
        FOR (LO) IN(0 AS LO0, 1 AS LO1, 2 AS LO2)
      )
WHERE (  LO0_DE IS NULL
      OR LO1_DE IS NULL
      OR LO2_DE IS NULL
      );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE M.AD (DE, AT, LO) AS
SELECT 1.01, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1.02, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1.11, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1.12, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2.01, 2, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2.02, 2, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2.21, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2.22, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3.01, 3, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3.11, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3.12, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3.21, 3, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| AT | LO0_DE | LO1_DE | LO2_DE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.02 | 1.12 | *null* |
| 2 | 2.02 | *null* | 2.22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C1O2lOPa)